# MS SQL Server 2016 - how to log record locking issues?

Tags: sql-server, locking

using MS SQL server 2016, we have sporadic transaction timeouts due to locking issues (once every 2 days).

The statement failing is `select ... (nolock) from table where id in (...,...,...,...).`

The activity is high and we couldn't find the cause of the issue.

My question: how is it possible, in case of rollback/timeout, to record in a log (event viewer, trace file, text file, anything) the statements run by the sessions causing the issue, so that we can figure out afterward what happened?

Thanks.

Comment: That is definitely not the correct syntax for `nolock`. which you shouldn't use anyway. What you need is either SQL Profiler or Extended Events, and look for `Lock Timeouts` and `Deadlocks`

Answer (score 0):

We use monitoring software SentryOne and Solarwinds offers the ability to monitor and record activity in the spids involved in blocking/deadlocks. I am not advocating using this software and running SQL profiler or extended events might give you the same results, I am just posting that this is how we do it.